# I can't follow the [timeline]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timeline) is being used for several different kinds of timelines, but its excerpt claims that it is specific to Facebook's timeline, and its tag wiki discusses both Facebook and ActionScript (and no tag should be so specific yet split).

I propose that, uh, something be done about this. I'd be happy to help with retagging given agreement on what the outcome should be.

I suggest that [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timeline) *not* be defined to be Facebook-specific as that would likely continue to be misused for other things. [facebook-timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline) already exists (and has the same Facebook-related tag wiki as the timeline tag) and appears to have the same amount of use within the [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) tag.

Comment: [tag:timeline] is a hopeless case. Burninate.

Comment: I've manually retagged all the posts related to Facebook Timeline to [tag:facebook-timeline], editing them to improve as I go along.

Comment: The tag wiki still talks about Facebook. What should be done with it?

Comment: I've suggested an edit for the tag wiki which removes the Facebook content. Not sure if I phrased it the best way.